# Beautifulsoup: Is it possible to get tag name and attribute name by its value?

Tags: beautifulsoup, attributes

I'm trying to scrape bunch of websites. All of them have one particular table with some changes. For example: if you check [this URL](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1645590/000164559021000008/a2021hpeproxy.htm#icaec13e17ee4432d9971f5e4b3d32ba1_265).

It has the attribute value `href="#icaec13e17ee4432d9971f5e4b3d32ba1_265"` and refers to the tag `<div id="icaec13e17ee4432d9971f5e4b3d32ba1_265"`. However, in another URL it is denoted by `<a name=...>..</a>`. So, I'll only have the attribute value `icaec13e17ee4432d9971f5e4b3d32ba1_265`. The tag name and the attribute name varies. How to get them with attribute value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a filter function that checks if there is one HTML tag with a attribute value equal to `value`:

```py
def your_filter(tag, value):
    for key in tag.attrs.keys():
        if tag[key] == value:
            return True
    return False

# alternatively as one liner:
def your_filter(tag, value):
    return any(tag[key] == value for key in tag.attrs.keys())
```

Then, you could use it like this:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code)
tags = soup.find_all(lambda tag: your_filter(tag, "icaec13e17ee4432d9971f5e4b3d32ba1_265"))
```