# filtering out elements found with beautiful soup based on a key word in any attribute

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, attributes, selenium-chromedriver, filtering

Here is an example of an url.

```
url = 'https://rapaxray.com'
# logo
html_content = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
images_found = soup.findAll('img', {'src' : re.compile(r'(jpe?g)|(png)|(svg)$')})
images_found
```

First I'm narrowing down the list of elements to the ones containing jpg, png or svg in a tag. In this case I only get 3 elements. Then I would like to filter those elements to show me only the ones that have a key word 'logo' in ANY attribute.

The element I'm looking for in this example looks like this:

'img alt="Radiology Associates, P.A." class="attachment-full size-full astra-logo-svg" loading="lazy" src="https://rapaxray.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/RAPA100.svg"/'

I want to filter out this element out  of all elements based on condition that it has a key word 'logo' in ANY of its attributes

The challenge is that:

- I have thousands of urls, and key word logo could be in a different attribute for different url
- logic: if 'logo' in ANY(attribute for attribute in list_of_possible_attributes_that_this_element_has) doesn't work the same way as list comprehensions because I couldn't find the way of how to access any possible attribute without using its specific name
- Checking all specific names is also problematic because particular attribute could exist in one element but not the other which throws error
- Case above is also extra challenging because attribute value is a list, so we would need to flatten it to be able to check if the key word is in it.
- For most of the urls the element I'm looking for is not returned as the top one like in this example so choosing top first is not an option.

Is there a way of filtering out elements based on a key word in ANY of its attributes? (without prior knowledge of what the name of the attribute is?).

Comment: why not just pickup the urls ending with your desired pattern ? which starts with http/https ?

Comment: because some of them like this one don't end with the pattern. Those that do, I can find, trying to find those that don't

Comment: well, in that case because limit your question to a specific one in order to be able to help you as we follow the community rules here, Kindly review [ask] and provide [mcve]. feel free to [edit] your question then.

Comment: The example I attached is the minimal reproducible example. Not sure why don't you like it? You say: 'why not just pickup the urls ending with your desired pattern?' because example I attached doesn't end with the desired pattern. And as I explained in my question the pattern could be hidden not just in 'scr' (the http you are talking about) it could be found in some other attribute.

Comment: Seems like a pretty clear request to me. At least as it currently is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you could use a filter function similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67770019/beautifulsoup-is-it-possible-to-get-tag-name-and-attribute-name-by-its-value/67770622#67770622) to search for all tags such that any tag attribute's value contains `val`:

```py
def my_filter(tag, val):
    types = ['.jpg','.jpeg','.svg','.png']
    if tag is not None and tag.name == "img" and tag.has_attr("src"):
        if all(y not in tag['src'] for y in types):
            return False
        for key in tag.attrs.keys():
            if isinstance(tag[key], list):
                if any(val in entry for entry in tag[key]):
                    return True
            else:
                if val in tag[key]:
                    return True
    return False

res = soup.find_all(lambda tag: my_filter(tag, "logo"))
```

Comment: just changed one line of your code because the url in 'src' do not necessarily ends with .png etc, but must have one of those file type extensions included. For example some 'src' looks like this: '/media/Images/Starr_Logo_Header.png?h=77&w=182&la=en&hash=2E9766B277C69EEA58015A3CBBD6842D'. Not sure if the changes will be visible to others. None the less all credit to you! Couldn't find the solution anywhere! It's the tag.attrs.keys() I didn't know about - now added it to my tool box thanks to you :)